# xpages jquery carousel not cycling as expected

Tags: jquery, xpages, carousel

I would like to make a carousel in Xpages that get's the pictures and caption text out of a notes view.

In my test database I have only 2 pictures with their corresponding text.

The carrousel starts with the item : active picture and text.

Then it starts cycling ; displays the second picture of the view with the corresponding text
then the carousel disapears
then it comes back and displays the first picture of the view
then displays the second picture of the view and STOPS
I would like it to cycle endlesly
What's wrong ?

```
<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->




            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!--  eerste afbeelding hard coded -->
                <div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
                    <img
                        src="servername/website.nsf/O/2CC047BB85CDD6B9C1257B030055835D/$FILE/Website_banner.jpg"
                        alt="" />
                    <div class="container" style="position: static;max-width:550px;padding-left:300px; margin-top:10px">
                        <div class="carousel-caption" align="center"
                            style="background-color: transparent;text-align:left">
                            <h1>Sample1</h1>
                            <p class="lead">
                                De nouveaux horizons pour les
                                enfants
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary"
                                href="#">
                                More info on sample1
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <xp:repeat value="#{view1}" var="thisDocument"
                    disableOutputTag="true" first="1">

                    <div class="item">
                        <xp:text escape="false"
                            id="computedField1">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:thisid= thisDocument.getColumnValue("unid");
  thisdocument = thisDocument.getColumnValue("Picture name");
  viewScope.put("captiontext", thisDocument.getColumnValue("frontpageText"));
  berekendelink= "<img src="+"'servername/website.nsf/O/"+thisid+"/$FILE/"+thisdocument+"' alt='' />";
  return berekendelink.toString();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>

                    </div>
                    <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField2">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:texttodisplay = viewScope.get("captiontext")
  return texttodisplay}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:repeat>

            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000 }); });
        </script>

    </xp:div>
```

Comment: This is rather a jquery question. For our jquery experts you want to edit the question and add the HTML result that gets send to the browser, so the trouble there can be pinpointed

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is working with following structure :

```
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{view1}" var="firstDocument" rows="1" first="0">

            here I've put a calculated field to calculate the reference of the first picture out of my view

          </xp:repeat>
        </div>

        <xp:repeat value="#{view1}" var="thisDocument" disableOutputTag="true" first="1">
          <div class="item">
            here I've put a calculated field to calculate the reference of the next pictures out of my view 
          </div>
        </xp:repeat>
    </div>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000 }); });
    </script>
</div>
```